# is_null function not working properly in my if statement

Tags: php, oop, logic

I have an if statement that detects if an user is logged in and belongs to a certain division. It really is quite simple.

There is a Permissions.php class, that returns the User object if logged in or NULL.

```
protected $user = NULL;
...
public static function instance() {
  if(!self::$instance) {
    self::$instance = new Permissions();
  }
  return self::$instance;
}
...
public function get_user() {
  return $this->user;
}
```

There is then the user.php class, that has functions to return what division they are in:

```
public function is_manager() {
  return $this->is_manager;
}
```

So I should be able to do the following:

```
if(Permissions::instance()->get_user()->is_manager())
```

But of course that might throw a warning about NULL objects, so I thought you could do the following:

```
if( ( ! is_null( Permissions::instance()->get_user() ) ) &&
    ( Permissions::instance()->get_user()->is_manager() ))
```

Which should check for null and if not, it should evaluate the other half of the if statement, but PHP for some reason, evaluates all of it and still complains about a NULL object (when the user is not logged in).

So then I broke the if statement up into a nested if statement, and PHP still complained about the null object, which led me to believe that the is_null method wasn't working as expected.

This worked in the end:

```
if (Permissions::instance()->get_user() != NULL) {
  if(Permissions::instance()->get_user()->is_manager()){
    ...
  }
}
```

**My question is, why did my code with the is_null function not work?**

---

Upon further testing, thanks to some of your great comments, it turns out that `get_user()` wasn't returning NULL, but `(bool)false` (from var_dump). Why is this strange behaviour exhibited? My class clearly sets it to NULL at the top and the function returns the variable as false?

Comment: Interesting. Is this reproducible on fiddle sites like [Ignite.io](https://ignite.io) or [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org)?

Comment: did you try the empty() function? it's a catch all: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: what happens if you do strict comparison in your working example `if (Permissions::instance()->get_user() !== NULL) {`? if it fails, then your problem is elsewhere, not with `is_null`

Comment: Did you try doing a variable dump on Permissions::instance()->get_user()? Or doing get class on Permissions::instance()? These should be somewhat informative.

Comment: @Passerby - sorry this is part of a much larger Kohana project. The time effort required, is substantial. I think there is enough code there for a quick test.php script if you would like to reproduce it. Also like i've said, my code works, I was just really intrigued by how PHP failed by design yet again.

Comment: Did you `var_dump()` the result of `Permissions::instance()->get_user()`, check if it really returns null? Anyway, apparently the `is_null()` is considered rather slow and it's better to use `!= NULL` comparison. You can also check the `empty()` function.

Comment: @thatthatisis var_dump was as expected. The permissions object is a newly instantiated object, and the get user returns either an User object or NULL>

Comment: @Husman and did you try strict instead of loose comparisson?

Comment: @MarkoD I already know that loose comparison works, so there is no point in testing strict comparison. And PHP's loose comparison is more useful to me, just incase my function at some point in the future return -1 or false instead of null. The language is full of holes and quirks! My question is to figure out why is_null() didnt work.

Comment: @Husman point of testing with strict comparison was to see if it is real null or not. if strict comparison fails, then it wasn't null in the first place, and that's why your `is_null` failed as well

Comment: @Husman https://ignite.io/code/51405573ec221e4024000000 I don't seem to be able to reproduce it. The reason I asked if _you_ can reproduce it, is because this looks quite unlikely, and chances are you missed something elsewhere. And also by reproducing the error, it _may_ help to find out where the problem is.

Comment: @MarkoD That is a very valid point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `!=` does not check the type (null is a type) and `get_user()` returned something like an empty string or false (see [PHP type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)).

Check the output of:

```
var_dump(Permissions::instance()->get_user());
```

Comment: Your right the output was '(bool)false', which is plain weird, as the variable is set to NULL and at no point does it get set to false.

Comment: "at no point does it get set to false" - you must have overlooked something, even in PHP variables don't change without cause.